# finding files and moving their folders

Tags: linux, shell, find, pattern-matching

I have a huge number of text files, organized in a big folder tree, on Debian Linux. What I need is to find all text files having a specific name pattern and then move the containing folder to a destination.

Example:

```
/home/spenx/src/a12/a1a22.txt
/home/spenx/src/a12/a1a51.txt
/home/spenx/src/a12/a1b61.txt
/home/spenx/src/a12/a1x71.txt

/home/spenx/src/a167/a1a22.txt
/home/spenx/src/a167/a1a51.txt
/home/spenx/src/a167/a1b61.txt
/home/spenx/src/a167/a1x71.txt
```

The commands:

```
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt"
mv /home/spenx/src/a12 /home/spenx/dst
mv /home/spenx/src/a167 /home/spenx/dst
```

The result:

```
/home/spenx/dst/a12/a1a22.txt
/home/spenx/dst/a167/a1a22.txt
```

Thank you for your help.

SK

Comment: Yes, the indicated find and move commands. But one by one it would take days. What I would like is a solution what goes through the src and moves the folders at the same time.

Comment: And what tools do you have at your disposal? Do you know anything about programming? Scripting with bash/perl/python/ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

combination of `find`, `dirname` and `mv` along with `xargs` should solve your problem

```
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt" | xargs -n 1 dirname | xargs -I list mv list /home/spenx/dst/
```

`find` will fetch list of files

`dirname` will extract path of file. *Note that it can only take one argument at a time*

`mv` will move source directories to destination

`xargs` is the key to allow output of one command to be passed as arguments to next command

For details of options used with `xargs`, refer to its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) of just do `man xargs` on terminal

Comment: This is! Does exactly what I want. Thank you all of you. SK

Answer (score 2):

You can execute:

```
    find /home/spenx/src name "a1a2*txt" -exec mv {} /home/spenx/dst \;
```

Font: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-find-move-all-mp3-file.html

Answer (score 1):

Create this `mv.sh` script in the current directory that will contain this:

```
o=$1
d=$(dirname $o)
mkdir /home/spenx/dst/$d 2>/dev/null
mv $o /home/spenx/dst/$d
```

Make sure it is executable by this command:

```
chmod +x mv.sh
```

Next call this command:

```
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt" -exec ./mv.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt" -exec mv "{}" yourdest_folder \;
```

Comment: This moves files to dest folder. OP wants dirs containing files to move.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably multiple ways to do this, but, since it seems you might have multiple matches in a single directory, I would probably do something along this line:

```
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 dirname | sort -u |
    while read d
    do
      mv "${d}" /home/spenx/dst
    done
```

It's kind of long, but the steps are:

1. Find the list of all matching files (the `find` part), using `-print0` to compensate for any names that have spaces or other odd characters in them
2. extract the directory part of each file name (the `xargs ... dirname` part)
3. sort and uniquify the list to get rid of duplicates
4. Feed the resulting list into a loop that moves each directory in turn